# Reference Parent Constructor Properties in Child Constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
function mild_bird(){
    this.name = "catherine";
    this.origin = "st petersburg";
    this.location = "brighton beach";
}

mild_bird.prototype.get_info = function(){
    return "poo" + ", " + "pee";
}

function wild_bird(nickname){
    this.nickname = nickname;
    //anyway to reference parameters in mild_bird constructor's?
    this.name = mild_bird.prototype.name;
    this.origin = mild_bird.prototype.origin;
    this.location = mild_bird.prototype.location;
}

wild_bird.prototype = new mild_bird();
wild_bird.prototype.constructor = wild_bird;

var the_wild_bird = new wild_bird("sandy");
alert(the_wild_bird.name);
```

The alert on the last line returns undefined.  I'd like it to return "catherine".  Is it possible to pass the properties in mild_bird's constructor to wild_bird's constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the parent's constructor inside the child constructor. Using `.call(this)` ensures that you set the context to the object, that is created by the childrens constructor.

```
function wild_bird(nickname){
    mild_bird.call(this);
    this.nickname = nickname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off your question:

> Reference Parent Constructor Properties in Child Constructor in JavaScript

Have a read of [John Resig's Simply Inheritance Model](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) - That should clear things up for you.